# c++ pass any child object with parent type to method

Tags: c++, object, dynamic, binding, virtual

I'm trying to pass a child object to a method, but do not know the object type ahead of time, other than that it will be inherited from a parent.
I can set the type as parent, and the compiler is happy, however I loose child data when this process takes place.

```
class Parent{
public:
Parent(int val);
};

class Child{
public:
Child(double childval, int parentval)
};
```

---

```
Child::Child(double childval, int parentval) : Parent(parentval)

Child childObj = new Child(cval, pval);
```

---

```
int someOtherMethod(Parent pobj);
someOtherMethod(childObj);  // Looses child data but parent data persists. How to keep child data too?
```

---

Is fine, however if I pass childObj into someOtherMethod the child data is lost, and only the parent data is maintained.

I have looked into virtual functions, dynamic binding, "set" but have become totally confused about which direction I should be taking.

Can someone please put me back on track?

Thanks.

Comment: post your real code, preferably compiled

Comment: "pass a child object to a method, but do not know the object type ahead of time" < isn't it mean the type is child????

Comment: @marcadian the object type could be any of about 4 inherited types, Child1, Child2 etc.

Answer (score 3):

If the information the Child posesses or the action the child takes, does not belong in the Parent abstraction, then you could determine who the child is by dynamically casting or checking a type.  However, as Edward Corlew mentioned this has some disadvantages.

Alternatively, you can ask the child who it is with a double dispatch.  This can be done by passing an object to the child then the child selects it's type.  The visitor can then collect whatever information it needs.

```
class Child1;
class Child2;

class Visitor
{
public:
  void DoStuff(Child1 & child1);
  void DoStuff(Child2 & child2);
};

class Parent
{
public:
  void DoStuff(Visitor & visitor);
};

class Child1 : public Parent
{
public:
  void DoStuff(Visitor & visitor)
  {
    visitor.DoStuff(*this);
  }
};

class Child2 : public Parent
{
public:
  void DoStuff(Visitor & visitor)
  {
    visitor.DoStuff(*this);
  }
};
```

Potentially, the visitor itself could be derived from and allow for different operations.  This removes the need for the spread of typechecking throughout the program.  However, the visitor class itself is coupled to the derived children and needs to be updated when concrete children are added.

Answer (score 2):

As Nemanja Boric pointed out, one option you have is to use a Dynamic Cast.  However, using a dynamic cast can be costly on some compilers such as MSVC, which will run string compares when evaluating the pointer.

Another option you have is to use a Static Cast.  Static Casts are evaluated at compile time so there's virtually no cost in using them.  However, you'll still have to have a way to identify your type of class in order to know what to cast it to.  In your base class you could have a pure virtual method called getType() which returns an enumerated value or an unsigned integer that represents an id for the class.  You then can check inside 'someOtherMethod' what type of id the class that got passed in has and then perform a cast to that type of class.

E.g.

Defined in some file is an enum with types

```
enum ClassTypes
{
    ClassType1,
    ClassType2,
    ...
};
```

As a side note: if you aren't changing what pObj points to you'll want to make the pointer
const.  It lets the reader know that you didn't intend anyone to change it and it's also
a form of defense programming against your greatest enemy (yourself) by making sure you don't accidentally change it and then try to perform a cast on it.

```
int someOtherMethod(Parent * const pObj)
{
    if(pObj == NULL)
        return 0;

    switch(pObj->getType())
    {
        case ClassType1:
        {
            Class1 * const pClass = static_cast<Class1*>(pObj);
            //Do stuff to class type 1
            break;
        }
        case ClassType2:
        {
            Class2 * const pClass = static_cast<Class2*>(pObj);
            break;
        }
    };

    return 1;
}
```

As you can see though this could grow very quickly and it doesn't handle duplicate code all that well.  Furthermore, Static Cast's can be dangerous because there's no check at run-time to see if what you're casting makes sense potentially leading to a crash.

You have to consider the design of the class itself. Maybe some of the code that you wanted to perform in this function you could perform in the class itself.  So instead of having to know the type you could simply say:

pObj->someOtherMethod(), where someOtherMethod is a pure virtual function all your children must define.  You may run into duplicate code across multiple method definitions again in which case some design patterns such as the NVI pattern might come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Project your classes wisely, use polymorphism and well-defined interface to obtain data from child classes.

However, if you need to do downcast in C++, you can do that with `dynamic_cast<T>`:

```
int someOtherMethod(Parent *pobj);
{
    Child1 *c1;
    Child2 *c2; 
    Child3 *c3;
    Child4 *c4;



    if((c1= dynamic_cast<Child1*>(pobj)) != 0)
    {
         /* Do stuff here, pobj is instance of Child1 */
    }
    else if((c2 = dynamic_cast<Child2*>(pobj)) != 0))
    {
       /* Do stuff here, pobj is instance of Child2 */ 
    }

    // ...
}
```

Pass your parameter as a pointer to the method, and you will need to have at least one virtual function in your class in order for this to work.